# Is it possible to switch from (SERVER = DEDICATED) to (SERVER = POOLED)

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, tns

I have a requirement to make use of POOLED connection dynamically.
The TNS has (SERVER = DEDICATED) which I need to use as (SERVER = POOLED) dynamically(Maybe by changing the JDBC or something),
Is it possible to do so ? Are there any alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing to SERVER=POOLED, you will be using DRCP which is the server side connection pool. DRCP requires server side settings as well. Refer to [DRCP document](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/database-resident-connection-pooling.html#GUID-D4F9DBD7-7DC6-4233-B831-933809173E39) for more details.